# JPA Specification - Filter nested list object

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have a entity `Order` with a list of tasks (another entity) and I need to use specification to filter the `Order` entity and the nested list of tasks.

Example:

```
Select * Order where taks.done = "S"
```

I need to return a list of order and tasks that was done.

My problem is the nested list, the specification filters only entity `Order` and not the list of tasks

```
public static Specification<Order> isDone(Indicator done) {
        return new JoinableSpecification<>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                Path<Indicator> path = this.joinList(root, UsuarioProcesso_.tarefas, JoinType.INNER).get(Task.done);
                return cb.equal(path, done);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use specification join. Example

```
(root, query, cb) ->
        {

            Join<Order, Task> taks = root.join(Task);
            Expression<String> expression = taks.get(Task_.done);
            Predicate predicate = expression.equals("s");
            query.where(predicate);
            return query.getRestriction();
        };
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar, the result has a filtred list of Orders but on tasks the result gets all tasks without filter. Code was add.